# PHP PDO, Binding not working

Tags: php, binding, pdo

Very new to this. My connection is working fine, I'm able to insert/select/delete from my database etc, but once I start trying to make it secure, using binding, it's just doing nothing. All afternoon I've been assuming that it's just the syntax, which I'm still getting used to, but I've tried everything and gone through countless tutorials. It all works, until I start binding. When I run the code below, nothing happens. After running it and checking my DB, there's been no insertion.

Here's my code right now... I've stripped it to the very basics. Shouldn't this work? What else could be wrong? I'm starting to think it's something wrong with my server or something.

```
<?php
//connection is working before this
$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO Players (Name) VALUES (:name)");
$query->bindParam(':name', 'John Smith');
$query->execute();
?>
```

Just in case, here's my connection routine....

```
try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxx;charset=utf8',
        'xx', 'xxx', array(
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, 
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
         ));
    echo "Connected";
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Having no problems with the connection.

Comment: It won't work because [`bindParam`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) requires second parameter as reference **variable**. And a **value** is not valid reference.

Comment: Try to remove the : from the bindParam maybe?

Comment: @pascalvgemert No it should work that way.

Comment: since you're setting it to exception mode, have you tried a `try/catch`?

Comment: You can also try `$query->execute(array('name' => 'John Smith'));`. @Rahil could be ;)

Comment: Thanks guys, fast replies. I just found my error log and spotted the error Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference. It's as Rahil says, I needed to set the value as a variable first, and pass that, so changed... 

    $query->bindParam(':name', 'John Smith');

To...

    $name = 'John Smith';
    $query->bindParam(':name', $name);

That's worked for now. I think what's making this difficult is that the tutorials are probably for different versions. I took my code directly from a tutorial so presumably that worked in the past?

Answer (score 0):

for bindValue(), the first parameter needs to be the identifier for the value, in your case it would be ':name'. The second parameter is the value that is being bound it would most likely be a variable passed to your method so it would be $name, take a look here

```
    $dbHandler = self::getHandler();
    // Prepare the Query:
    $stmtHandler= $dbHandler->prepare("INSERT INTO Players (Name) VALUES (:name)");
    // Bind the value:
    $stmtHandler->bindValue(':name', $name);
    // Execute the Query:
    $stmtHandler->execute();
```

php.net would probably do a better job explaining it for you [HERE](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php)

Hope it helps you.